# Creating new tag synonyms for limnology

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-management

Not many casual biologists (and certainly very few non-biologists) know what the field of [limnology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limnology) refers to. As such, I would think that a number of questions that would appropriately receive the [limnology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limnology) tag have not (and do not) receive the tag. (e.g., a search for "lake" brings up 82 results that otherwise have no limnological tag associated with them).

So I proposed two tag synonyms for [limnology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limnology)

- aquatic-biology
- freshwater-biology

My reasoning was to allow someone searching for tags referencing two well known terms ("freshwater" and/or "aquatic") to get to the appropriate [limnology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limnology) tag.

I was assuming that suggesting these tag synonyms was the appropriate way to do this. However, I had to create these two new tags in order to actually suggest them as synonyms. Is there a different way to propose "synonyms" for improving the ability to search for appropriate tags without having to create new tags? In other words, can a non-existent tag synonym just be added directly to an existing tag?

Comment: anybody have thoughts about this??

Comment: I think it's a bit problematic because limnology need not be specific to freshwater, and aquatic-biology need not be specific to limnology but I am sympathetic to what you hope to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the point of joining [limnology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limnology) and [freshwater-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freshwater-biology), since they are so close to each other (as @BryanKrause points out, limnology is a bit broader though). However, [freshwater-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freshwater-biology) is sort of the parallel to the existing (and useful) tag [marine-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marine-biology) (so maybe [freshwater-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freshwater-biology) should be the "main" tag?). Placing [aquatic-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquatic-biology) as a synonym isn't really appropriate though, since it is much broader than limnology (can cover to both limnology, marine biology and freshwater biology).

All in all, I think making [freshwater-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freshwater-biology) a synonym is a good idea - people can still search for and use that tag (in relation to [marine-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marine-biology)), but it will be reclassified as limnology.

Comment: Yes I like the comparison of [tag:freshwater-biology] to [tag:marine-biology] -- that dichotomy would suggest that perhaps [tag:freshwater-biology] should be the main tag and [tag:limnology] be made a synonym. I see both your and @BryanKrause's points about [tag:aquatic-biology]; I think you're both right and I'm not really sure what I was thinking when I first suggested a narrower application of that tag. I guess we maintain [tag:aquatic-biology] too? or eliminate it with the idea that the more specific  [tag:freshwater-biology] and [tag:marine-biology] tags serve most purposes well enough?

Answer (score 2):

**Suggested Solution:**

As discussed in this Q&A's comments and in fileunderwater's post, I think the best thing to do moving forward is:

1. **[freshwater-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freshwater-biology) should be made the main tag (i.e., the "master") and [limnology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limnology) be made a synonym.**
2. I think an [aquatic-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquatic-biology) tag would be ok to keep in instances where water in general (i.e., irrespective of marine vs fresh) is the focus.

   - This tag should not be made a synonym of either [freshwater-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freshwater-biology) or [marine-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marine-biology). (In other words, **my synonym suggestion for [aquatic-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquatic-biology)should be deleted** -- can I do that myself??).

**Approach:**

I suggested these tag edits over a month ago, but only 1 other member seems to have high enough rep in [limnology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limnology) to vote on the pending tag suggestion. However, a few members discussed these suggestion here in meta, and we seem to be in agreement about how to move forward with these tags.

**Can I ask one of the current mods (@Chris, @WYSIWYG, @MadScientist) to make these changes?**

I'm very certain that the [freshwater-biolgy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freshwater-biolgy) tag could be assigned to numerous existing questions and would be very useful to new users (especially since few people know what `limnology` is).

- I think we should "clean this up" sooner than later to help us better assign water-related posts the appropriate tags.

Comment: Maybe tomorrow *you* can make these changes ;)

Comment: @canadianer nope, guess not :p ha!